# How to create a json file artifact from a CodeBuild resource inside a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am defining a CodeBuild resource inside my CloudFormation template.

Inside the CodeBuild resource I have to define my build spec.

This is my `Source` property inside my `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` resource:

```
"Source": {
                "BuildSpec": {
                    "Fn::Join": ["\n", [
                        "version: 0.2",
                        "phases:",
                        "  build:",
                        "    commands:",
                        "      - echo '{}' > output.json",
                        "artifacts:",
                        "  type: zip",
                        "  files:",
                        "    - output.json"
                    ]]
                },
```

But I get an error saying `YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: did not find expected key at line 5`. What am  I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I put a space after the : in the json object. What worked for me was echo {"\"key\"":"\"value\""}